# How do I put quotations marks from a formula into a .setvalue in script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having an issue trying to work out how to put the quotations marks into the import range formula when using the below code. Any help is appreciated.
James

```
function myFunction() {
    var master = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Mysheetid'); 
    var resultsheetname = ("Results - " + todaysdate); 
    var sheet = master.getSheetByName(resultsheetname);
    var sheetname = ("Vote - " + todaysdate);
    var sheetid = sheet.getSheetId();
    var importrange = ('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'sheetid'/edit#gid=","'sheetname'!b9:f14")')
    sheet.getRange('c16').setValue();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create the formula as a string, you can do it this way:

```
var importrange = '=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sheetid + '/edit#gid=","' + sheetname + '!b9:f14")';
```

---

Please be careful:

1. `todaysdate` is not defined in the function.
2. you need to provide the formula string to the setValue() method: `sheet.getRange('c16').setValue(importrange);`

And just to make the code cleaner, you don't need the parentheses when defining `resultsheetname`, `sheetname` and `importrange`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your respones, Ive made the suggested changes. Also that's for helping me clean the code I'm new to this.
Ive tried again with the changes to code and returned the following error?
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSheetId' of null (line 7, file "linking pages")

Comment: I then hard coded the id..
   var importrange = '=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + 'MYID' + '/edit#gid=","' + sheetname + '!b9:f14")';
    sheet.getRange('c16').setValue(importrange);
but got this error?
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 9, file "linking pages")

Comment: fixed my issue.
    var todaysdate =  Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+10", "dd/MM")
The above code needed to be at the top above the var's using it

Comment: Glad you fix your issue, but remember that the correct way to insert a formula would be with the [`setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormula(String))